# Как объяснить инверсию подлежащего и сказуемого?

Tags: синтаксис, инверсия

**Жили Артамоновы ни с кем не знакомясь** (М. Горький).

Но, может быть, и так неплохо: "Артамоновы жили ни с кем не знакомясь"?

**Зачем** М. Горький применил инверсию?

Спасибо за ваше внимание и ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вера, почитайте. Очень интересно.[Конструкции произведений Горького](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=743.Wwm52t3Aom0-jcAA3O1bx3HKp0LwS7G9AXMwS4F1ubDaElckj32KmANmo1Eq8yz0MXoS8pbPM43FIaSUx9Pz7A.6e761889421527c1415e2aea8edf06e455c62720&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9cUEbBkAQk_OhAzHcv9PulIpF4ylKJ2-qA&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejR0eWJFYk1LdmtxbG93OHNLcXF3Tk1NLXNoaWhPQ0xvRm5OSGRTZHRFQ2VzRVVaQW9oTWZaeFFFcUJiYmozdHN3Nk5LaXZNcmVKNUVkQXgyMklLQUF5VHVqTWRPX0JSdy1DR0h1T0Ywd3c4c1YzUmFCc3NSTEN5Rjdwa1VQU0Z2NA&b64e=2&sign=76abd7ee5e32be26fcee196bc1ce4914&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ7IXge4WdYJQW9NxnjWmbq18uLialtklYVTXv1IJBZIjJmCxKVlCMOoCm8NGJ1lOqnRGWZQily_6C_zuwTZC7z6UapPagIZj4M1AAVLfT6Tln6_imoLZrq00Tw016NXMXmzg8_49jDoR1vlzxiNkb4aCuRjA-kcRx31UrYoNRLuCCzn1-pLo6J8zApy3h1hehIqQ6A0PmEmqHzSgKTeCzn6&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpH3muVOPFaVAuYrb2kKH2Z2rVQxM_nd2za61XmogeIBCA7NduqQCrtvF6ZovZ6W8lLU3OsFdOR1HozqOz8ALyKebqJ8ITlAttcl-9D3QlEh6JPZVdpuHRt_uESiYagyGkS3eoR5NQrfQF-EijalTZb0NzDREfhyrXaLnIT5JAyNZN0cpAD8VUj-BtZa0OEKcFPxlTySt_Ej2RhynAAoyTqUUo0JiGiq5_&l10n=ru&cts=1436353450788&mc=5.5632831833908325)

Comment: Да, спасибо, мне показалась интересной следующая фраза: "Стоит отметить и такой факт, что инверсия в горьковских рассказах создаёт особый ритм фраз, ритмомелодический рисунок, предполагающий вдумчивое, осмысленное прочтение и постижение авторской мысли".  Инверсия всегда изменяет ритмомелодику, отсюда особая напевность речи, объемность фраз, художественность пространства. Так преодолевается линейность письма - один из самых распространенных недостатков  начинающих писателей.

Answer (score 3):

Видимо, о существовании Артамоновых говорилось незадолго до этого, т. е. читателю как бы уже сообщено, что они "жили-были". Настало время рассказать, "как" они жили, и для этого автор, возможно, задумавшись, не повторяется ли он, при помощи инверсии сделал акцент на глаголе.

Comment: Alex_ander, а почему инверсия  акцентирует глагол, ведь и при нормальном порядке слов  на него падает ударение:Артамоновы жИли (пауза) ни с кем не знакОмясь.

Comment: Это не связано с ударением. При таком порядке слов глагол обращает на себя внимание, поскольку получается аналог топикализации: предмет рассмотрения выносится в начало (на нехарактерную позицию) и производит впечатление заголовка, после чего происходит раскрытие свойств вынесенного. Можно посмотреть на это как на упрощение относительно явного оборота "Что касается того, как они жили, ...". Более распространено перемещение обстоятельства времени с целью переноса акцента между временем и связанным с ним событием -здесь примерно то же самое, просто реже встречается.

Comment: Спасибо, по поводу заголовка очень интересное мнение. Но почему вы думаете, что с ударением инверсия никак не связана, можно же сказать, что глагол выделяется логическим ударением? И как вы вообще понимаете логическое ударение, есть ли у этого понятия сколько-нибудь точное определение?